# In C how to read the output of a process and write it in the input of another?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, dup

Hi I have a C programme that is basacally suppose to simulate the pipe function in linux and write the amount of bytes that are read in a .txt file so
`./a.out cat test : grep -v le : wc -l`

The problem that I'm trying to figure out is

Why is the same amount of bytes written in the file since I know each process returns a different amount ?

This piece of code is executed in the parent and is trying to count the amount of bytes of each output with a read syscall and writes the output in a write syscall in the next process so that the next process can use the output as his input.

So let's say I have these pipes `a | b | c`
This code will read the output of `a` and write it in `b` so that `b` can use it as it's input and so on.

```
 for (int i = 1; i < processes-1; i++) {
       
       close(apipe[i][1]);
       char str[4096];
       int count=0;
       int nbChar=0;
       
       while(1){
                count=read(apipe[i][0],str,sizeof(str));
                nbChar+=count;
                if(count==-1){
                    if (errno == EINTR) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        perror("read");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }else if(count==0)break;
      }
      char *leInput=(char*)malloc(nbChar*sizeof(char));
      strncpy(leInput,str,nbChar);
      if(i>0){
        fprintf(fp, "%d : %d \n ", i,nbChar);  
      }
      close(apipe[i][0]); 
      write(apipe[i+1][1], leInput, nbChar);
      
     
  }
```

Comment: Each time you call `read()` you're writing to the beginning of `str`, overwriting what you read the previous time through the loop.

Comment: So there aren't `nbChar` characters to copy to `leInput`.

Comment: but i reset the loop after each process so doesn't the next process have access to a new str?

Comment: I'm talking about the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time through the `while(1)` loop you're read into the beginning of `str`, not where you left off in the previous iteration. So you're overwriting the previous read with the next read.

You should copy incrementally to `leInput` each time through the loop. You can then use `realloc()` to grow it to accomodate the new input, and you can use `leInput + nbChar` to copy after the place where you finished the previous time.

```
for (int i = 1; i < processes-1; i++) {
       
    close(apipe[i][1]);
    int nbChar=0;
    char *leInput = NULL;
       
    while(1){
        int count=0;
        char str[4096];
        count=read(apipe[i][0],str,sizeof(str));
        if(count==-1){
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if(count==0) {
            break;
        }
        leInput = realloc((nbChar + count)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(leInput + nbChar, str, count);
        nbChar += count;
    }
    if(i>0){
        fprintf(fp, "%d : %d \n ", i,nbChar);  
    }
    close(apipe[i][0]); 
    write(apipe[i+1][1], leInput, nbChar);
}
```

Alternatively you could just write to the next pipe in the inner loop, without collectiong everything into `leInput`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < processes-1; i++) {
    int nbChar = 0;

    close(apipe[i][1]);
       
    while(1){
        int count=0;
        char str[4096];
        count=read(apipe[i][0],str,sizeof(str));
        if(count==-1){
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if(count==0) {
            break;
        }
        write(apipe[i+1][1], str, count);
        nbChar += count;
    }
    if(i>0){
        fprintf(fp, "%d : %d \n ", i,nbChar);  
    }
    close(apipe[i][0]); 
    close(apipe[i+1][1])
}
```